# button onclick="handle_clicks()" .. handle_clicks is not defined AND can i use (this) as a parameter in html element.onclick?

Tags: onclick, this

Can you inspect this code and find out why is it not working well?
there are two things i want to clarify..
Why is the function is not defined?
can i use (this)?

HTML:

```
In head:
<script src="script.js"></script>

In body:
<button type="button" onclick="handle_clicks(this)">button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="handle_clicks(this)">button2</button>
```

JS:

```
   window.onload = () => {
    function handle_clicks(btn) {
      btn.style.background = 'green';
      console.log('A button was clicked');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste your script tag at end of body, and call js function like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="handle_clicks(event)">button1</button>
```

Now in JS use simple function without windows.onload

```
function handle_clicks($event) { // $ is used for events
   const elm = $event.target
   elm.style.background = 'green';
   console.log('A button was clicked');
}
```